# PHP associative array sorting by previous value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following array that I'm trying to sort. The value is where the key should come after in the final output array.

```php
$main = array(
    'lorem' => 'lorem',
    'ipsum' => 'duis',
    'sit' => 'adipiscing',
    'duis' => 'sit',
    'amet' => 'elit',
    'consectetur' => 'lorem',
    'adipiscing' => 'consectetur',
    'eiusmod' => 'ipsum',
    'labore' => 'eiusmod',
    'dolore' => 'labore',
    'magna' => 'dolore',
    'incididunt' => 'magna',
    'tempor' => 'incididunt',
    'sed' => 'tempor',
    'elit' => 'sed',
    'aliqua' => 'amet'
);
```

The final output would be like this.

```php
$final = array(
    'lorem' => 'lorem',
    'consectetur' => 'lorem',
    'adipiscing' => 'consectetur',
    'sit' => 'adipiscing',
    'duis' => 'sit',
    'ipsum' => 'duis',
    'eiusmod' => 'ipsum',
    'labore' => 'eiusmod',
    'dolore' => 'labore',
    'magna' => 'dolore',
    'incididunt' => 'magna',
    'tempor' => 'incididunt',
    'sed' => 'tempor',
    'elit' => 'sed',
    'amet' => 'elit',
    'aliqua' => 'amet'
);
```

I've been trying to wrap my head around an appropriate approach but I seem to be taking myself down the wrong paths. I keep ending up with only some of the elements following the correct rules. How would you tackle this? I tried looping, splicing and searching in many ways with no luck.

Edit: uncleaned attempt

```php
$final = array();

$main = array_merge($current_word_types, $word_types);

foreach ($main as $id => $previousWord) {
    $final[$id] = $previousWord;

    if ($id === $previousWord) {
        continue;
    }

    if (isset($word[$id])) {
        continue;
    }

    $previousKey = array_search($previousWord, $main );
    $previousKeyIndex = array_search($previousWord, array_keys($main ));

    $final = array_slice($final, 0, $previousKeyIndex, true) +
                array($previousKey => $main [$previousKey]) +
                array_slice($word, $previousKeyIndex, NULL, true);
}
```

Edit 2: Here are the master lists I built `$main` from

```php
// master ordering list
$word_types = array(
    'lorem' => 'lorem',
    'ipsum' => 'lorem',
    'sit' => 'ipsum',
    'duis' => 'sit',
    'amet' => 'duis',
    'consectetur' => 'amet',
    'adipiscing' => 'consectetur',
    'eiusmod' => 'adipiscing',
    'labore' => 'eiusmod',
    'dolore' => 'labore',
    'magna' => 'dolore',
    'incididunt' => 'magna',
    'tempor' => 'incididunt',
    'sed' => 'tempor',
    'elit' => 'sed',
    'aliqua' => 'elit'
);

// items that ended up getting special order treatment due 
// someone reordering the words so the $main output to needs 
// to compensate for this. (this could end up empty at times)
$current_word_types = array(
    'lorem' => 'lorem',
    'consectetur' => 'lorem',
    'duis' => 'consectetur',
    'amet' => 'duis',
    'elit' => 'amet'
);
```

Comment: You really just need to find the one element that comes at the end (here: "aliqua", it's not contained in the array's *values*) and start with that. Then you can get the previous element simply by key (`$main['amet']`), and [splice](http://php.net/array_splice) it to the front of the array. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: please show some code-effort you have tried so far?

Comment: @deceze, good approach, I will only add that the reverse is also possible. Find the one that has the same key and value and use that starting point to get the next one. Now you have the same approach but from top to bottom.

Comment: @Wimanicesir Sure, but it requires repeated searching through the array's values, which is probably less efficient.

Comment: @deceze, Not if you use array_flip. However, yours will still be more efficient :)

Comment: array_flip cannot be used here because of duplicate values

Comment: I'd recommend marking the initial value as an empty string. Currently, having a value that should come after itself is a bit confusing.

Comment: @ServingQuarantineperiod, You use array flip after you know the starting point. I see no problem then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that will sort the array the way you want. It is based on @deceze algorithm (described in the comments to the question), using [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to find the key which is not also a value, and then iterating back through the array until the key matches the value at that key:

```php
function sorter($array) {
    // find the key which doesn't have a matching value
    $unique = array_diff(array_keys($array), $array);
    $key = reset($unique);
    $value = $array[$key];
    $result = array($key => $value);
    // follow the values backwards until the key matches the value
    while ($key != $value) { 
        $key = $array[$key];
        $value = $array[$key];
        $result = array($key => $value) + $result;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Output of `print_r(sorter($main))` for your data:

```php
Array
(
    [lorem] => lorem
    [consectetur] => lorem
    [adipiscing] => consectetur
    [sit] => adipiscing
    [duis] => sit
    [ipsum] => duis
    [eiusmod] => ipsum
    [labore] => eiusmod
    [dolore] => labore
    [magna] => dolore
    [incididunt] => magna
    [tempor] => incididunt
    [sed] => tempor
    [elit] => sed
    [amet] => elit
    [aliqua] => amet
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OkDhv)

Answer (score 0):

Working from the front of the array, use a loop to seed the first element in the result array as well as populating a mapping array.

Use a second loop to populate the result array in the desired order. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/s9JsB))
([Or with no isset() calls](https://3v4l.org/I5gBd)) ([another alternative](https://3v4l.org/8Q85g))

```
foreach ($main as $k => $v) {
    if ($k === $v) {
        $result[$k] = $v;
        $key = $k;
    } else {
        $map[$v] = $k;
    }
}

while (isset($map[$key])) {
    $result[$map[$key]] = $key;
    $key = $map[$key];
}

var_export($result);
```